# Ghostscript - reembed font

Tags: ghostscript

I want to user ghostscript to optimize pdf files.

My files are generated by iText, and there is font which is embeded too many times - 3000+;

I want to repring document with ghostscript, which will remove all embeded and embed it only once in file.

Do you know how to do it ?

And additional question - is there any difference detween ghostscript and ghost4j ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, most likely. Without seeing the file I cannot be certain, but the probability is that each font is embedded as a subset. That is it contains just a few of the glyphs that were originally present in the font.

So if the first instance contains, say a, c, f and g and the second instance contains b, e and h you can see that the two fonts are actually different.

Worse, the text is usually re-encoded, so the character codes are not what you would expect. In the example above, 'a' would not have the character code 0x61 (ASCII for 'a'), it would have the character code 1. c would be 2, f would be 3 and so on. **But** in the second case, character code 1 would be 'b', character code 2 would be 'e' etc.

There's no easy way to recombine the multiple font subsets, and also re-encode each set of text to the 'combined' font.

Where the pdfwrite device detects multiple subset fonts which have compatible encodings (the character codes used are unique in each font) it will combine them together. It won't attempt to re-encode them again though, so if the two fonts use the same character codes (as per my example above) pdfwrite will just emit two fonts.

Assuming you've already tried running the file through pdfwrite and didn't get the result you wanted, then that's it, you can't achieve the result you want with the current code.

Probably you can tell iText not to subset the fonts, which will solve the problem for you at the source, rather than trying to fix it afterwards.